# Write right-to-left text on images with Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I Want to write some Persian or Arabic text on an image. I used the [Intervention Image](https://image.intervention.io/v2) package for doing that, but the text was generated in reverse. How can I have the text placed in the correct (right to left) direction?

```
$rarticle = Article::first();

$test = storage_path($rarticle->image);
$image = Image::make($test);

$image->text($rarticle->title, 120, 100, function($font) {
    $font->file(base_path('/admin-theme/assets/fonts/yekane.ttf'));
    $font->size(40);
    $font->color('#4285F4');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('bottom');
    $font->angle(0);
});

$image->save(storage_path($rarticle->image));
```

The generated image: [image: image showing text written left to right]

Comment: See also this [open issue](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/630) on the project asking for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should download Arabic package https://sourceforge.net/projects/i18n-arabic/

and

require('./I18N/Arabic.php');

```
// Add styled text to image
$TITLE1 = "محمد مصطفي محمد مصطفي محمد مصطفي ";
$Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Glyphs');
$text1 = new \NMC\ImageWithText\Text($Arabic->utf8Glyphs($TITLE1), 2);
$text1->align = 'right';
$text1->color = 'FFFFFF';
$text1->font = dirname(__FILE__) . '/I18N/DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf';
$text1->lineHeight = 36;
$text1->size = 24;
$text1->startX = 0;
$text1->startY = 0;
$image->addText($text1);
```

[image: Example]

[source](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/1073)

Answer (score 1):

First install package **eskandari/persianrender**:

`composer require eskandari/persianrender`

Then use it in your code :

```php
$persian_text_rev = \PersianRender\PersianRender::render('فارسی');

$persian_text = '';
for ($i = mb_strlen($persian_text_rev); $i>=0; $i--) {
    $persian_text .= mb_substr($persian_text_rev, $i, 1);
}

$image->text($persian_text, 120, 100, function($font) {
    $font->file(base_path('/admin-theme/assets/fonts/yekane.ttf'));
    $font->size(40);
    $font->color('#4285F4');
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('bottom');
    $font->angle(0);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work well with Arabic, the letter (ي) gets rendered as  (ى)

Comment: @EyadMohammedOsama This package produced and tested for Persian, Did you use with arabic font ?

Comment: Yes I did !
Anyway, i ended up using this package instead: https://www.ar-php.org/en_index-php-arabic.html